# bundler 1.1 ignoring platforms

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am trying to include ruby-debug or ruby-debug19 based on ruby version.

I've tried specifying the platform on the gem line,

```
gem 'ruby-debug', :require => nil, :platforms => :mri_18
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => nil, :platforms => :mri_19
```

in a block, and finally this, where I include the dependencies, and nothing works.

```
group :development do
  platforms :mri_18 do
    gem 'rbx-require-relative', '0.0.9', :require => nil
    gem 'linecache', '0.46', :require => nil
    gem 'ruby-debug', :require => nil
  end

  platforms :mri_19 do
    gem 'linecache19', '0.5.12', :require => nil
    gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => nil
  end
end
```

It keeps trying to install linecache on ruby 1.9.3.

It seems to be a problem with the dependencies or something, because I can limit `SystemTimer` to `:mri_18` on the gem line and it works.

Comment: Bundler 1.1 has not yet been released, please [open an issue with them](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/new) if you're having problems with it.

Comment: It came out yesterday: http://rubygems.org/gems/bundler

Comment: Gahh you're right. I was looking at the tags on http://github.com/bundler/bundler not carlhuda's repo. It also still says "coming soon" on the [homepage](http://gembundler.com/). Still, probably not a bad idea to open up an issue with them `:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lesson here kids is to check your dependencies twice!

The platforms work fine, but I had another gem that was depending on `ruby-debug` so it was getting pulled in anyway. Putting said gem in the `mri_18` platform made it work.